# Round to highest .5 value in mysql

Tags: mysql, rounding, floor

I am trying to round the value to highest 0.5 value.

For example if i execute

```
 select round(5.456);
```

Then I want to get the result as 5.5 and if I execute

```
select round(5.73434);
```

Then I want to get the result as 6.

That is if value is between 0 and 0.5 then it must be rounded to 0.5 and if the value is between 0.5 and 1 then it must be rounded to 1.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like ceiling(x * 2)/2 - if my hazy memory of primary school arithmetic serves

Answer (score 7):

Might not the cleanest solution, but should do the trick:

```
select (CEILING(5.456 / 0.5) * 0.5)
```

`CEILING` is returning the higher value as shown in [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceiling).

Answer (score -2):

You need to pass the second parameter to the function `round`.

See documentation: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round)

So, in your case, `select round(5.456, 1);` will give you the expected result.

Comment: when I execute SELECT ROUND(5.756, 1); I am getting 5.8. But instead I require 6 as output

Comment: It's OK to test answers before posting them

Comment: @Strawberry, my bad. I missed the second part of the question. Got a little excited i guess.

Comment: @rjirji. Yes it will. My answer will fail in the second condition given in your question. *facepalm*

Comment: It fails ALL conditions

Comment: @Strawberry you too should "test comments before posting them". Do TRY `select round(5.456, 1);` and lemme know what it returns.

Comment: `select round(x,1)` round to 1 decimal. So `round(5.44,1)` gives ... ? ( for the impatient: `5.4` )

Comment: The answers still here for some reason

Comment: The answer is true for the 1st example, but does not solve the question.

Comment: The answer is coincidentally true for the first example, but so is `SELECT 5.5;`